# Modbus library, error: Connection failed: Result too large

Tags: c++, modbus

I am new to modbus implementation and I am trying to develop client and server application.

server side when I am trying to connect, Connection is failing

```
int main()
{
    modbus_ctx *ctx;

    ctx = modbus_new_tcp("127.0.0.1", 1502);

    if(ctx == NULL)
    cout << "unable to allocate libmodbus context" << endl;

    if(modbus_connect(ctx) == -1)
    {
        fprint(stderr, "Connection failed: %s\n", modbus_strerror(errno);
        modbus_free(ctx);
        return -1;
    }

    ...... //rest of the code

    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code, I get following message:

```
Connection failed: Result too large
```

Above code I have taken from the sample code provided in the modbus library 'test' folder.

I want to know what I am doing wrong? how should I fix this issue?

Comment: Is your Modbus slave really running on port 1502?

Comment: @Ronaldo, yes client is also running on the same port i.e 1502, on local host